Power consumption in AC circuit
In a purely resistive circuit, maximum power is consumed. Why? Because, we say, current and voltage are in phase. While in a purely inductive circuit, power consumed in a cycle is zero. Because, current and voltage are out of phase.
But why no power is consumed when the two are out of phase? Is it that charge feels no hinderance when voltage is zero while current is maximum? I am not able to visualize it.

In a purely inductive circuit (resistance is zero) connected to sinusodial voltage, the phase shift between voltage and current is 90 °. At the maximum voltage, the current is zero, at the maximum current, the voltage is zero. The energy is floating into to the inductor and back without loss and no power is consumed. This is only a theoretical example, there is no real inductor with zero resistance.

@ Uwe What I am asking is why of what you have said is happening. How to see that?

If you take an inductor with resistance, the phase shift between voltage and current is less than 90 ° and power is consumed within the resistance.

Because inductors and capacitors are energy storage devices. When there is a constant current through an inductor or constant voltage across a capacitor, there is no change in the amount of energy stored in their respective internal magnetic or electric fields. When you apply a time-varying input or signal to them, they will store or release energy. When you apply a periodic (repeating) input, then the net energy change from one full cycle to the same point in another cycle is zero (in steady state).
The voltage/current phase relationship isn't exactly what causes net energy consumption to be zero, but is also a consequence of being an energy storage device since to store more energy in an capacitor, there must be an increase in voltage, i.e. capacitor current is proportional to the derivative of capacitor voltage and differentiating a sine function results in a cosine function.

Consequence of all these is that no energy is dissipated in the inductor, while dissipation takes place in the resistor. Cannot we say it is because current and voltage are in phase in the resistor.

@KeShAw I think the answer basically was no. The reason is that resistor does not store energy, but dissipates everything immediately. So that is the reason why current and voltage are in phase.
